# ¿Comó lograr que se sume un número de una lista por cada registro nuevo?

Tags: python, lista, tuplas

Tengo este problema:

Debo crear una identificación con los siguientes parámetros:

**Tomo**

Lo define el lugar de nacimiento. Si el Lugar es San José, el tomo es  1, si el lugar es Alajuela el tomo es 2, si el lugar es Cartago el tomo es 3 y si el lugar es Heredia el tomo es 4.

Es decir en una cédula el tomo es el primer dígito de la misma.

Ejemplo:

```
                **2** 1 1 5 0 0 8 5 0


                    Tomo
```

**Folio**

Es un valor numérico que representa la página del tomo donde quedó registrado el nuevo nacimiento. Debe ser hasta de 4 dígitos.

El folio cambia cada 100 registros, por lo que para efectos del programa va a ser un valor fijo, el cual va a estar almacenado en una tupla, para cada Tomo habrá un Folio distinto, es decir,

```
    TOMO        FOLIO   POSICIÓN EN LA TUPLA
         1      1201            0
         2      1150            1
         3       950            2
         4      1001            3
```

Por ejemplo, dentro de mi código tenemos

```
tuplaFolio=(1201,1150,950,1001)
```

En la cédula de identidad el folio representa los 4 siguientes dígitos del tomo. Ejemplo:

```
2 **1150**  0 8 5 0
```

**Asiento**

Es un valor numérico que representa al número de registro del recién nacido dentro del folio. Debe ser hasta de 4 dígitos.

El Asiento cambia cada vez que se registre un nuevo nacimiento, por lo que el sistema deberá realizar el proceso de aumentar el asiento para cada uno de los nuevos bebés registrados.

Para realizar el proceso se trabajará con una LISTA DE ASIENTOS inicial, es decir con un valor inicial según el lugar de nacimiento (tomo), para cada Tomo habrá un Asiento distinto, es decir,

```
    TOMO        ASIENTO     POSICIÓN EN LA LISTA
         1       1000           0
         2       0850           1
         3       0788           2
         4       0445           3
```

En mi código tengo

```
asiento=[1000,0850,0788,0445]
```

En la cédula de identidad el asiento representa últimos 4 dígitos de la cédula. Ejemplo:

```
2 11 5 0  **0 8 5 0**
```

Por el momento he logrado esto, pero no sé como aumentar el asiento por cada registro (que es una lista) y que el programa no me pregunte 4 veces por la provincia de nacimiento.

```
folio = (1201,1150,950,1001)
asiento = ["1000","0850","0788","0445"]

def provincia_nacimiento():
    print("Ingrese una de las siguientes provincias 'San José', 'Alajuela', 'Cartago', 'Heredia'")
    lugar = input("Ingrese provincia de Nacimiento: ")
    if lugar == "San José":
        tomo = 1
    elif lugar == "Alajuela":
        tomo = 2
    elif lugar == "Cartago":
        tomo = 3
    elif lugar == "Heredia":
        tomo = 4
    return tomo

def cedula_id():
    if provincia_nacimiento() == 1:
            print(1,folio[0],asiento[0])
    elif provincia_nacimiento() == 2:
            print(2,folio[1],asiento[1])
    elif provincia_nacimiento() == 3:
            print(3,folio[2],asiento[2])
    elif provincia_nacimiento() == 4:
            print(3,folio[3],asiento[3])

cedula_id()
```

Comment: ¿Porqué usas valores de cadena (string) para los asientos? Podrías usar valores enteros y sería más fácil realizar el incremento a los mismos.

Comment: lo intente con valores enteros, pero python no acpeta que enpiece con "0".

Comment: Igual puedo cambiar los valores para que inicien en otro número, pero tampoco dabría como realizar el incremento.

Comment: Una sugerencia: Por qué no cambias provincia_nacimiento() para que muestre una lista corta de texto en plan "1: San José, 2: Alajuela...etc" y acepte un numero del 1 al 4 en lugar de escribir el nombre completo? Pienso que seria más conveniente y menos susceptible a error del usuario

Comment: Por que no usas valores enteros como dice Patricio Moracho y luego si necesitas mostrar el dato, lo conviertes en cadena y lo rellenas con 0 usando zfill? Algo así como str(asiento).zfill(4).